How to correctly build and run a react-native expo project with BLE
I am building a program to link my esp23s3 dev module to a react-native expo app. So far I have coded the esp32 to send out a ble signal of a simple counter now when I code the front end I cannot run it on my emulator (bc of bluetooth reasons). Then I tried to run it on the expo go app which also didnt work because of problems between the react-native-ble-plx package and expo. So, then I found information that I needed to build my project is there a way to do this without buying the apple developer subscription? (currently I will run the project and see a development server in my expo go app that I cannot click on).
